# Rails Redirect Route Bad Host Component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I'm trying to make a redirect in my routes.rb. I'm getting an error when I leave off my domain.

```
match "/partners/" => redirect("/partners.html")
```

Navigating to /partners/ gives this error page:

```
URI::InvalidComponentError

bad component(expected host component): frontend_rails.dev
```

However, it does work if I put our full domain in the redirect.

```
match "/partners/" => redirect("http://example.com/partners.html")
```

But for my dev server I don't like links to go to our production server. According to the rails doc, this should be added automatically:

> In all of these cases, if you don’t provide the leading host (http://www.example.com), Rails will take those details from the current request.

Any ideas why it's not liking my relative redirects? Thanks!

Comment: Try leaving off a few characters: The last `/` of the match and the `.html` extension of the target: `match "/partners" => redirect("/partners")`. It should fit the [Rails API Docs Example](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html#method-i-redirect) this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost a year later and I finally realized what the problem was. It actually WAS a bad URI. The repo in GitHub was called frontend_rails. I used the Pow server, which gives you a host based on your folder name (which, when you check out a project defaults to the name of the GitHub repo), so http://frontend_rails.dev.

However, underscores technically aren't allowed in a URI. This was tripping up the URI gem. I symlinked my project frontend_rails to frontend-rails and now it works. Voilà !

Comment: heureka! took me an hour to figure this out as well. Thanks for posting the solution.